# elasticsearch, поиск IP в диапазоне

Tags: запрос, elasticsearch

Есть документ с описанием используемого диапазона ip в сетях:

```
{"lan_1":{"ip_start":"192.168.0.1", "ip_end":"192.168.0.20"}}
{"lan_2":{"ip_start":"192.168.0.20", "ip_end":"192.168.0.30"}}
{"lan_3":{"ip_start":"192.168.0.101", "ip_end":"192.168.0.149"}}
```

mapping для `ip_start` и `ip_start` выставлен: `type:ip`.

Задача состоит в том что бы отправить запрос с указанием `ip`, в ответ получить имя сети (`lan_1`, `lan_2` или `lan_3`) к диапазон которой он входит.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю стоит посмотреть в сторону написания скрипта. В [статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/252067/) рассмотрен похожий на ваш случай пример.

За основу плагина взят [плагин](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-native-script-example) одного из разработчиков.

Задача которую решает плагин: для заданного времени time сортировать события так, чтобы активные события (start <= time <= stop) были в начале выдачи.

Пример такого документа:

```
{
  "start": "09:00:00",
  "stop": "18:30:00"
}
```

Модель плагина:

```
public class Event {
    public static final String START = "start";
    public static final String STOP = "stop";

    private final LocalTime start;
    private final LocalTime stop;

    public Event(LocalTime start, LocalTime stop) {
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
    }

    public boolean isInProgress(LocalTime time) {
        return (time.isEqual(start) || time.isAfter(start))
            && (time.isBefore(stop) || time.isEqual(stop));
    }
}
```

Весь код плагина доступен на [GitHub](https://github.com/s12v/elaticsearch-plugin-demo)

Запрос:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/demo/event/_search?pretty" -d'
{
  "sort": [
    {
        "_script": {
          "script": "in_progress",
          "params": {
            "time": "15:20:00",
            "use_doc": true
          },
          "lang": "native",
          "type": "number",
          "order": "desc"
        }
    }
  ],
 "size": 1
}'
```

Результат:

```
{
  "took" : 139,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 86400,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "demo",
      "_type" : "event",
      "_id" : "AUvf6fPPoRWAbGdNya4y",
      "_score" : null,
      "_source":{"start":"07:40:01","stop":"15:20:02"},
      "sort" : [ 1.0 ]
    } ]
  }
}
```